# Dropbox iOS API - How do i end the session?

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox, dropbox-api

I have successfully connected to Dropbox using their iOS API, I now want to be able to disconnect from Dropbox through an IBAction, how do I do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a button with IBAction and then try calling the method `deleteCredentials` which is located in DBKeychain.h and also the `unlinkAll`. Never used the Dropbox SDK, but this looks like it should disconnect you.